# OData Service Returns 404

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am following the "Application Best Practices Example" in the OpenUI5 docs.
In the [Component Configuration step](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/170638b7a2b4424e8580fb473af6a3cd.html) I use the same value for "serviceUrl" that is configured in the guide:

```js
serviceUrl : "/uilib-sample/proxy/http/services.odata.org/V2/(S(sapuidemotdg))/OData/OData.svc/"
```

However this url is converted to a address in "localhost" in the actual app. I can see in the Chrome Dev Tools Console that I get a 404 response when trying to get this URL. As a result of this, I cannot see a list of products or add a new product to the service, as you can see in this screenshot: [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukFX6.jpg)
How I am supposed to configure the OData Service URL to get read/write access to the Products List?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uilib-sample-application has a server side proxy servlet, which returns the content of whatever URL is given to it.

So you either need a proxy-servlet on your "localhost" machine or a local service that you can use. The alternative (for testing) is to use chrome and start it with the "--disable-web-security" parameter, then you can use the real service URL.